# Compare lambda expressions pointers by value

Tags: python, .net, lambda, functional-programming

Consider the following Python program:

```
a = lambda x: x
b = lambda x: x
print(a == b)
```

This obviously outputs *False* although, which is clear why it happens. However, this is counterintuitive. I wonder if there is any programming language (not academic-only) that is able to do a structural comparison of lambda expressions and would print *True* in the example above? If this doesn't work out of the box, is there any smart way to compare lambda expressions at all? How about the .NET abstract syntax trees?

Edit: As I got the answer, here is working example:

```
# Applies an argument arg to a function f.
apply = lambda f, arg: lambda *args, **kwargs: f(arg, *args, **kwargs)
# Compare two functions by their co_code (see answer below)
equals = lambda l0, l1: l0.__code__.co_code == l1.__code__.co_code

# Defines a function that adds 2 to a provided number.
add_two_0 = apply(add, 2)

# Another way of adding two is twice adding 1.
add_two_1 = apply(apply(add, 1), 1)

# The following statement prints True
equals(add_two_0, add_two_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the code objects won't do what you want: two different functions will have different code objects.

You could compare the bytecode of each function, though, which you can get with `co_code`:

```
(lambda x:x).__code__.co_code
# b'|\x00\x00S'
(lambda y:y).__code__.co_code
# b'|\x00\x00S'


(lambda y:y+1).__code__.co_code
# b'|\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x17S'
(lambda y:y-1).__code__.co_code
# b'|\x00\x00d\x01\x00\x18S'
```

So, your comparisons would give, as expected:

```
(lambda x:x).__code__.co_code == (lambda y:y).__code__.co_code
# True
(lambda y:y+1).__code__.co_code == (lambda y:y-1).__code__.co_code
# False
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need another programming language. Python *can* do it.

```
>>> (lambda x: x + 1).__code__ == (lambda x: x+1).__code__
True
```

P.S.: I didn't downvote your question. In fact, I think your question is valid. It's probably someone who newly acquired the ability to downvote. Don't worry about it; one-two reputation points don't matter much.

Comment: Your statement evaluates to True, which is interesting. However, in my example above, I get the result that I would have expected: a.__code__ == b.__code__ evaluates to False.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your comment. Do you expect `a.__code__ == b.__code__` to evaluate to `False`?

Comment: I just tested it and a.__code__ == b.__code__ evaluates to false. I expected this outcome because of how Python works. Of course, I asked for a way to make it evaluate to true. Using the __code__ function doesn't help, because it does a kind of stupid comparison. For example, try (lambda x: x).__code__ == (lambda y: y).__code__ which evaluates to False as well although it the same function.

Comment: Let me make this a bit more clear: a == b evaluates to False. I expected this, but it's not what I am looking for. a.__code__ == b.__code__ evaluates to False. I also expected this, but it's not what I am looking for. (lambda x: x + 1).__code__ == (lambda x: x+1).__code__ evaluates to True. I didn't expect this, this could be what I am looking for, but it is not, because just renaming the variables makes it evaluate to False like in (lambda x: x).__code__ == (lambda y: y).__code__

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
a = lambda x: x
b = lambda x: x
print(a.__code__ == b.__code__)
```

Comment: Well, that prints True, but

a = lambda x: x
b = lambda y: y
print(a.__code__ == b.__code__)

prints False, which is not what I am looking for, because a and b are still equal.